# Uncaught ReferenceError: Web3 is not defined Solidity

Tags: web3js, javascript, error, web3-providers

I've been working with this project and I downloaded all dependencies and Web3 already but when I test my code it shows me this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Web3 is not defined
```

in line 120.

This is my code:

```
<script>
if(typeof web3 !== 'undefined'){
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider); -this is where it errors
}else {
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545")); 
}

web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];

var SuffrageContract = web3.eth.contract('example');
var Suffrage = SuffrageContract.at('example');
console.log(Suffrage);
```

I have already tried several methods like declaring

```
web3 = required('web3');
```

but it is still not working.

Comment: Can you please include more? Sanity check: did you include the `web3.js` file?

Comment: Yes I included web3.js

Comment: try including `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js/dist/web3.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Thank you Mr. Achala Dissanayake! My project is running now!

Comment: Yes. :) You rock dude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope you are using `web3` as browser module.

As in their [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/#as-browser-module), you can add the CDN link using `<script>` tags as below,

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Cant up this because I have less than 1 rep. But anyway thanks! Its working now because of you. :)

Comment: @JeffNUCode Hope you can up now :D

Answer (score 1):

Are you wrapping this code with a `window.addEventListener('load',...)` handler?

Read here: [Web3 - Ethereum Browser Environment Check](https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#partly_sunny-web3---ethereum-browser-environment-check)

> Note that the environmental `web3` check is wrapped in a `window.addEventListener('load', ...)` handler. This approach avoids race conditions with web3 injection timing.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

  // Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask)
  if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
    web3js = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
  } else {
    console.log('No web3? You should consider trying MetaMask!')
    // fallback - use your fallback strategy (local node / hosted node + in-dapp id mgmt / fail)
    web3js = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
  }

  // Now you can start your app & access web3 freely:
  startApp()

})
```

Comment: It still didn't work. I guess it will be easy if I post my whole code here.

Comment: Not the whole code, a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: not the whole code my bad

Comment: Just edited my question.